# cross compiling opencv 2.4.5 for arm board (beaglebone black) on ubuntu- Linking CXX shared library error at 92%

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile opencv for my beaglebone black. All seemed well until I added python support to the cmake flags, since im going to be needing the python wrappers for my project.

I have numpy and python-dev installed, and I'm currently running python 2.7.3. 
I installed both with:
`sudo apt-get install numpy`
`sudo apt-get install python-dev`

This is what I'm getting:

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_python
[ 92%] Building CXX object modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o
**Linking CXX shared library** ../../lib/cv2.so
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so when searching for -lpython2.7
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpython2.7.a when searching for -lpython2.7
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm using the available toolchain provided in the linux dist of opencv for arm devices. I really didn't change anything else aside from that.

Is there something wrong with my python dependencies?

cmake flags used:
cmake -DSOFTFP=ON  -DENABLE_NEON=ON –D BUILD_ZLIB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../opencv-2.4.5/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your CMake reports, it finds only x86 variant of Python. So you'll need some embedded Linux distro like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) to avoid dealing with dependency hell, i.e. you'll need to cross-compile Python, numpy and all its dependencies and embedded Linux distro would take this job from you.

But there are more issues. One of the biggest problems lies in numpy dependencies like [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) etc. These libraries are not very good suited for cross compilation.

OpenEmbedded seems to have recipes for OpenCV with Python support. In Buildroot it is still a work in progress.